# opposite of mutate_at in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need the opposite of mutate_at in dplyr.  I want to select a group of columns not specified in the variable list.

```
df <- tibble(var_not_to_be_modified = sample(c("T","F"),10, replace = TRUE),
             var_to_be_modified     = sample(c(1,0)    ,10, replace = TRUE) )

df %>%
mutate_at(c("var_not_to_be_modified"), as.numeric)
```

Result would be to change var_to_be_modified to dbl.

Comment: `mutate_at(vars(-var_not_to_be_modified), as.numeric)`. You can do anything in `vars()` that you can do in `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning @Axeman's comment into an answer as community wiki:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(., vars(-var_not_to_be_modified), as.numeric)
 # A tibble: 10 x 2
#   var_not_to_be_modified var_to_be_modified
#   <chr>                               <dbl>
# 1 F                                       1
# 2 F                                       1
# 3 F                                       1
# 4 F                                       1
# 5 F                                       1
# 6 T                                       0
# 7 T                                       1
# 8 F                                       1
# 9 F                                       0
#10 T                                       1
```

From the help page of `vars`:

> Arguments
>
> ...    Variables to include/exclude in mutate/summarise. You can use same specifications as in select(). If missing, defaults to all non-grouping variables.

Answer (score 1):

If we are passing a character vector, use `one_of` which is the canonical way to remove columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("var_not_to_be_modified"))), as.numeric)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   var_not_to_be_modified var_to_be_modified
#   <chr>                               <dbl>
# 1 F                                       1
# 2 F                                       1
# 3 T                                       1
# 4 F                                       0
# 5 T                                       0
# 6 F                                       1
# 7 T                                       1
# 8 T                                       1
# 9 F                                       0
#10 T                                       1
```

According to `?select_helpers`

> one_of(): Matches variable names in a character vector.

---

If we pass a column name that is not in the data, the behavior is different.  Here, it wouldn't end up in an error

```
 df %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(-one_of("hello")), as.numeric)
```

and

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-hello), as.numeric)
```

> Error in is_character(x) : object 'hello' not found

In other words, if the OP wanted the whole pipeline to end up in an error, the second option is better and if it still works, but with a warning, the option in this post can be used

Comment: Why do you say `one_of` is the canonical way to do this? Using bare column names in `vars` seems much closer to what dplyr users are already familiar with and what you would use with `mutate_at` anyway